# Firefox cache lost when it crashes

Tags: firefox, crash, browser-cache

I'm usually in a slow internet connection, and everytime Firefox isn't closed correctly, I kind of lose part of my cache. When I open it again, I see pages start loading everything, including images that were in cache most of the time, etc.

Is there any helpful extensions, settings, etc. for my problem?

Or, is there a way I can manually save the cache, and replace it with a backup in case it happens?

Comment: Related: [Why is Firefox's cache empty after an improper shutdown?](http://superuser.com/questions/471367/why-is-firefoxs-cache-empty-after-an-improper-shutdown)

Answer (score 1):

Check out these two pages:

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/control-how-firefox-caches-websites-with-better-cache/
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/firefox-cache/

The first one seems more promising, but make sure that you check your cache options in the Options->Privacy.

I would also look into why Firefox keeps crashing, there can be more to this.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Firefox doesn't *keep crashing*. Yesterday, for example, I went out and left my laptop running on battery

Comment: @codehitman "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: In this case, the first link describes the better-cache module and for the second link I mentioned the most important bit with "The first one...". I don't think quoting the entire post would be any helpful. But I will bear that in mind for the future thanks.

Comment: @codehitman well, that didn't help. The bettercache extension isn't available anymore.

Comment: Depending on your Firefox version try this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cachedownload/